# AWS CloudFormation /var/log/cloud-init-output.log equivalent for Windows AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudformation

When creating a Linux AMI in AWS with CloudFormation, I can view the output of the Cloud Init scripts, for example if I have a UserData section that echoes to stdout:

```
"UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                "echo hello, stdout\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Then `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` will contain these lines:

```
+ echo hello, stdout
hello, stdout
```

What is the equivalent log file for Windows AMIs? Is it somewhere in `http://169.254.169.254/`, or is it a log file somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) you have to wrap `UserData` with `<script></script>`. The log is written to either `C:\Logs` or `C:\Log` depending on whether `EC2Launch` or `EC2Config` is used.

According to the same document, this should work on all Windows instances by default unless you expressly use [`EC2Config`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html#UsingConfigInterface_WinAMI).

> By default, all Amazon AMIs have user data execution enabled for the
>   initial boot. For instances using the EC2Config service, you can
>   specify that user data must be executed on the next boot or restart of
>   the service. For more information, see Ec2 Service Properties.

Even more information is available on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7677578/492773).

Comment: There was no `C:\Log` but I found `C:\cfn\log` which contained `cfn-init.log`.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 2016 AMIs that's `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log`, where ProgramData is a hidden folder...