# CloudFormation template to bring up EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Using CloudFormation template, I brought up a Windows 2012 EC2 instance. Instance came up fine. I read that metadata related to this instance is all recorded in the Ec2config logs which is in one of the sub-folders of `C:\Programfiles\Amazon\` directory.

Following are the steps that I am doing after EC2 instance comes up:

1. Rename the Administrator password (which doesn't work yet).
2. Set the time zone
3. Rename the hostname
4. Adding that server to the domain controller.
   There should be some kind of logs on that EC2 instance about all these steps right? However, I can't find any. Any suggestions where I should be looking for the logs please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358862/aws-cloudformation-var-log-cloud-init-output-log-equivalent-for-windows-amis/47088260#47088260

Comment: What is your question? You just said "any suggestions", but you didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run cloud-init scripts to achieve all the tasks. I recommend writing PowerShell scripts for this.

Just refer the below repo, you will find useful template and scripts which do same activities.

https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-microsoft-sql